# Reduce Gap between HTML <UL> and <LI> elements

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have below HTML in my web page:

```
Forum
<ul>
<li> Stack</li>
<li> OverFlow</li>
</ul>
```

And as you could see below, I get the items listed perfectly, but there is a fixed gap between `<UL>` and `<LI>` elements.

[image: HTML Output]

Is there a way, I can reduce this gap? i.e. gap between "Forum" and "Stack" text in attached screen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The gap does not exist between `UL` and `LI` elements, but between the `Forum` text and the `UL` element. Most browsers define a default margin around certain elements, like the `UL`.

You get rid of it with CSS:

```
ul { margin: 0; }
```

or if you just want to reduce it, for example this one will set 0 margin for horizontal, 5px for vertical:

```
ul { margin: 5px 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this (don't know if it's the problem with you):

```
<ul><li>
your first li element </li><li>
your second li element</li>
</ul>
```

There are spaces that you can't avoid on HTML code if you don't "avoid" it, let's say. 
Take a look [here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Comment: +1!  This is actually the most hidden and infuriating cause, especially in horizontal lists.  The browser reads whitespace between the <li> elements.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to kapa's comment, if you enter a negative value for the margin it will reduce the gap.

In css:

```
ul { margin:-20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use CSS. In your CSS, specify the margin or padding properties to adjust the spacing between your `LI` and `UL` elements.

`LI
{
    margin: 0px;
}`

Comment: li paddings do not affect outer spaces from them.

Comment: @Jazza, Yes you did, but your snippet mentioned `padding` which clearly does not affect the spacing inside `<ul>`. Thus is irrelevant to the OP's question.

Comment: I apologize if I offended you. :)

Comment: I apologise for my response. You are correct, I just thought you were rubbing it in my face :\

Comment: No, I wasn't rubbing it anywhere, certainly not on your face. Just wanted you to correct your answer, which you did. Great, how about +1

Answer (score 0):

This will decrease the vertical distance, but not the horizontal.

```
ul { margin:-15px 0;}
```

It is a combination of Andrew and kapa's.

[Here's how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGdzc.png)