# HTML gap before/after listing (<ul>)

Tags: html, css, vba, excel

I have a problem with a HTML body in VBA. I create an email and fill the information with HTML.

The discription of my problem is discribed here: 
[Reduce Gap between HTML <UL> and <LI> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322288/reduce-gap-between-html-ul-and-li-elements)

BUT I can not use this in my VBA( can I? )

Is there a solution to reduce the gap with HTML only?
Or can i use CSS in my VBA HTML body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define this within the `<style>` tags in the `<head>` of the html using CSS. Some thing along the lines of:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        ul { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Rest of your html goes here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS reduce the gap for ul, li:

```
ul, li
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your css file

```
ul, li
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
list-style:none;
}
```